# is my code breaking GOOGLE adsense terms and conditons

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

```
<div id='adHolder'>
adsense code here
</div>

//on dom ready
jQuery('#adHolder').css('something','somevalue');
```

-i have placed my adsenese code inside a div and repositioning it on dom ready, i want to know- is iam breaking google adsense TERMS & CONDITIONS

-i also want to know- is performing some javascript/jquery actions on parent element(div in my case) containing google adsense code breaks google adsense terms and condition.

Answer (score 0):

That in and of itself? No. However, what CSS are you using? Are you trying to make the div hidden so the client still loads the ad but doesn't have to see it or something? Or putting it behind another div? Those would be violations.

But no, there's nothing inherently wrong with modifying a parent element of an adsense block. That's your code. Just don't break how the adsense block looks or make it so the user can't see it.

Comment: iam having 3 zones left,middle and right on my site. i  have kept my right zone empty and have placed one add there. on dom ready iam doing jQuery('#addHolder').css('position','fixed').css('top','10px');.
Now google add is always visible (even on page scroll) and its not overlapping any other element.

Comment: That seems fine, but why not just set that CSS property statically? You don't really need jquery for it.